# ionic 2 CSRF failed

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic2, csrf

i taked CSRF failed error;

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Response
_body: "{"detail":"CSRF Failed: Referer checking failed - no Referer."}"
headers: Headers
ok: false
status: 403
statusText: "Forbidden"
type: 2
url: "https://deneme.com/api/v1.0/channels/"

my codes;

```
uyegiris()
{
  var veri,kullaniciveri;
  this.deneme=2;
   var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
    //headers.append('Authorization' , 'Basic '+ btoa(tok));
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let postParams = {
      username: this.user['usernameil'],
      password:this.user['password'],
    }

      this.http.post("https://deneme.com/api/v1.0/users/login/", postParams, options).timeout(2000)
      .subscribe(data => {
        veri = data['_body'];
        veri= veri.slice(1, -1);
        veri = veri.replace(/\\/g, "");
        veri = JSON.parse(veri);
        console.log(veri);
        if(veri.msg_err)
          {
         let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
         title: 'Giriş Hatası',
         subTitle: veri.msg_err,
         buttons: ['Tamam']
        });
        alert.present();
        }
        else
           { 
            this.kanallistele();
           }
       }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.deneme=error;
      });
}

kanallistele()
{
 var veri;
    this.kanallardiv=true;
    this.uyegirisdiv=false;
    this.kanallistelebtn = false;
    this.kanallistelebtn2 = false;
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    //headers.append('Authorization' , 'Basic '+ btoa(tok));
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    let postParams = {
    token: "381f13d7056-ce5fe474919",
    user_id: "71",
    }
    var veris="channel_name_";
    this.http2.post("https://deneme.com/api/v1.0/channels/", postParams, options)
      .subscribe(data => {
        veri = data['_body'];
        console.log(veri);       
        veri= veri.slice(1, -1);
        veri = veri.replace(/\\/g, "");
        veri = JSON.parse(veri);
        for(var i = 0 ;;i++)
          {
              if(!veri.channel_list['channel_name_' + (i)])
                    break;   

              this.veriler.push({channelname: veri.channel_list['channel_name_' + (i)],channelid: veri.channel_list['channel_id_' + (i)]});              
          }
       }, error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.deneme=error;// Error getting the data
      });  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with Ionic. Looks like your server / backend / whatsoever requires some CSRF tokens in order to respond to your request and you do not attach them. You should contact your backend team in order to add the missing tokens to your request

Comment: but my project dont give me error on browser but I try to on android device give me error.

Comment: most likely your browser has some cookie that is automatically sent with the request and contains those tokens. The thing is anyway on your backend - Ionic cannot be the reason here